# Codeignitor image not showing

Tags: php, image, .htaccess, codeigniter

I am using codeignitor 3. The image is not displayed in the page except for the index() page.

```
<img src="image/logo.jpg" alt="..." width="500">
```

I am having the same image tag in index page and it is working fine. But for other pages it is not working. This is my ht.access file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /bookflix/
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Please help me solve this

Comment: Can you test your .htaccess [`here`](https://htaccess.madewithlove.com/) by checking for an image URL ?

Comment: Change the image url to `src="/image/logo.jpg"` and try again. Adding `/` in front of the image url makes it relative from the document root, while not having the initial slash will make it relative from the current url in the browser (which will then be incorrect on sub pages).

Comment: @nice_dev It says in
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)

Unsupported TestString: $1

So what shuld I do??

Comment: @M.Eriksson I did this..And it is not working

Comment: @Divya Can you share the testing link of that site please?

Comment: @nice_dev The project is running in localhost bro

Answer (score -1):

1.- Check if your path of your images is correc, because you mentioned that the image tag works fine on the index() page. If the image is located within the images directory at the root level of your CodeIgniter project, then the relative path to the image should be images/logo.jpg. Make sure this path is correct in the image tag.

2.- Look the base URL configuration:
The base_url configuration plays an important role in generating URLs. Check your config.php file in the application/config directory. Ensure that the base_url is correctly set. It should look something like this:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://yourdomain.com/bookflix/';
```

3.- View File Location:
Make sure that the view files where you're including the image tags are in the right location. If you're using a different directory structure, adjust the path accordingly.

4.- Url Function:
URL Helper that can be used to generate URLs. This can help ensure consistent URL generation. To use it, load the URL Helper in your controller or autoload it in the autoload.php configuration file.

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

Then, you can use the base_url() function to generate the URLs:

```
<img src="<?= base_url('images/logo.jpg') ?>" alt="alt-image-text" width="500">
```

5.- Make sure that your images are indeed located within the images directory at the root level, and this directory is accessible to the webserver.

6.- Check errors on console tnspect your browser's console for any errors related to loading the image. This can provide more insight into what might be causing the issue.
7.- Ensure that your web server (Apache) is configured to allow serving files from the necessary directories, sometimes server configurations might restrict access to certain directories.

Comment: Point 1, 3, 5 and 7 seems irrelevant here. 1. If it was **images**/logo.jpg instead of **image**/logo.jpg, it wouldn't work on the first page either. 3. The view locations are completely irrelevant. As long as CI can find the views (which it seem to be able to), they will be rendered into a single HTML document before being sent to the client. 5. Again, since it works on the first page, it's safe to assume they are located where they should. 7. Look at point 5. Point 2 and 4 could be a recommended way to do it. Use those to write a proper example instead.

Comment: @M.Eriksson. I check everything and the images are indeed located in the image folder. And it is working in my index page which  is my concern. If it worked in the index page the same code should work in other pages also right. I even tried to include the base_url as said but still no luck.